# How can I access my Google account while overseas?

Tags: google-account, multi-factor-auth, google-authenticator

I received an email from Google today that says, starting 6 days from now, after I enter my password I'll need to complete a second step on my phone to log in.

The problem is that I'm overseas, so I cannot use my US simcard. I travel about 6 months per year, to various countries.

I could change my phone number to my local number, but the next time I switch countries I will not be able to log in to switch it again, because my local simcard will not work in the next country. Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/25908/88163

Answer (score 2):

### Use a different 2FA

Since you'll be traveling so often (making [backup codes](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1187538) alone not an appealing option), you should switch from text or voice codes to authenticator codes. What this means is that instead of getting a text message, you just open an app and copy the current code. You can even access the codes when your phone doesn't have internet or any cell service.

See

- [Get verification codes with Google Authenticator](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1066447) (iOS, Android)
- My [answer about using an authenticator extension](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/171823/197614) (desktop browsers)

Answer (score -1):

You should deactivate the "2-Step Verification" feature in your Google Account by setting this profile setting option off under https://myaccount.google.com/security

Ideally you should do this before the six days are over.

EDIT: Official Support documentation - https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1064203?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DiOS&oco=1